# Simple function literal produces missing parameter type

Tags: scala

With Scala 2.12, I can do this:

```
Try("3").fold(_.toString, _.toString)
```

but I can't this:

```
Try("3").fold(_.toString, _)
```

This is the error I receive:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function
```

Why a complicated expression does work and a simple one doesn't?

My workaround:

```
Try("3").fold(_.toString, x => x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first snippet is equivalent to

```
Try("3").fold(x => x.toString, y => y.toString)
```

Your second snippet is equivalent to

```
x => Try("3").fold(y => y.toString, x)
```

This needs a type annotation, because the type of `x` cannot be inferred from context.

If you want to pass the identity function, you can just pass the pre-defined [`identity`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#identity[A](x:A):A) method from `Predef` via [η-expansion](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion-section):

```
Try("3").fold(_.toString, identity _)
```

Or even [implicit η-expansion](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#method-conversions):

```
Try("3").fold(_.toString, identity)
```